# Bootstrap modal with inline TinyMCE drop-down menu items misaligned

Tags: tinymce, bootstrap-modal

I'm using inline TinyMCE inside a bootstrap modal and when opening a drop-down menu item e.g.:"Formats", the items are shown aligned to the top-left corner of the page, instead of appearing where they should.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

There's yet another problem with inserting links, when you click on the link menu item, it opens the TinyMCE model but it doesn't let you input anything on the inputs.

**Found solution for this last problem with this:** [tinyMCE in a bootstrap dialog.](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorials:TinyMCE_in_a_boostrap_dialog)

Repro on [this js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marinagon/nez0z0z3/).

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'h2.editable',
  inline: true,
  toolbar: 'undo redo',
  menubar: false
});

tinymce.init({
  selector: 'div.editable',
  inline: true,
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
    'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste'
  ],
  toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
  content_css: [
    '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
    '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
  ]
});
```

```css
h2.mce-content-body {
  font-size: 200%;
  padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

body {
  background: transparent;
}

.content {
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 0;
  min-height: auto;
  padding: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.6.4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="editable">
          <h2><img title="TinyMCE Logo" src="//www.tinymce.com/images/glyph-tinymce@2x.png" alt="TinyMCE Logo" width="110" height="97" style="float: right" />TinyMCE Inline Mode</h2>
          <p>
            This is an editable div element.
          </p>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tincidunt est ac dolor condimentum vitae laoreet ante accumsan. Nullam tincidunt tincidunt ante tempus commodo. Duis rutrum, magna non lacinia tincidunt, risus lacus tempus ipsum, sit amet
            euismod justo metus ut metus. Donec feugiat urna non leo laoreet in tincidunt lectus gravida. Sed semper ante sed dui consectetur eget commodo eros imperdiet. Mauris magna diam, scelerisque at ornare vel, dignissim ac sem. Fusce id congue
            lacus. Duis sit amet tellus erat. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus mattis facilisis pretium. In in nibh eu urna ornare semper. Sed imperdiet felis vitae nibh sagittis eu pulvinar
            metus facilisis. Sed dolor orci, aliquet sagittis auctor id, faucibus at justo.
          </p>
          <p>
            Vestibulum vestibulum velit nec magna lobortis elementum. Ut egestas ultrices tincidunt. Sed vestibulum mi vitae dui interdum eget rhoncus neque faucibus. Ut nec leo tellus. Nunc in metus sit amet purus bibendum dignissim pulvinar quis erat. Quisque vel
            ultricies nisi. Vestibulum eu ante risus. In ultrices dignissim massa, vel luctus dui consequat quis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image: Inline TinyMCE dropdown menu items opened inside a bootstrap modal]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with `tabindex="-1"` attribute on the modal. If you remove it, it will work like expected.

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'h2.editable',
  inline: true,
  toolbar: 'undo redo',
  menubar: false
});

tinymce.init({
  selector: 'div.editable',
  inline: true,
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
    'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste'
  ],
  toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
  content_css: [
    '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
    '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
  ]
});
```

```css
h2.mce-content-body {
  font-size: 200%;
  padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

body {
  background: transparent;
}

.content {
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 0;
  min-height: auto;
  padding: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.6.4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="editable">
          <h2><img title="TinyMCE Logo" src="//www.tinymce.com/images/glyph-tinymce@2x.png" alt="TinyMCE Logo" width="110" height="97" style="float: right" />TinyMCE Inline Mode</h2>
          <p>
            This is an editable div element.
          </p>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tincidunt est ac dolor condimentum vitae laoreet ante accumsan. Nullam tincidunt tincidunt ante tempus commodo. Duis rutrum, magna non lacinia tincidunt, risus lacus tempus ipsum, sit amet
            euismod justo metus ut metus. Donec feugiat urna non leo laoreet in tincidunt lectus gravida. Sed semper ante sed dui consectetur eget commodo eros imperdiet. Mauris magna diam, scelerisque at ornare vel, dignissim ac sem. Fusce id congue
            lacus. Duis sit amet tellus erat. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus mattis facilisis pretium. In in nibh eu urna ornare semper. Sed imperdiet felis vitae nibh sagittis eu pulvinar
            metus facilisis. Sed dolor orci, aliquet sagittis auctor id, faucibus at justo.
          </p>
          <p>
            Vestibulum vestibulum velit nec magna lobortis elementum. Ut egestas ultrices tincidunt. Sed vestibulum mi vitae dui interdum eget rhoncus neque faucibus. Ut nec leo tellus. Nunc in metus sit amet purus bibendum dignissim pulvinar quis erat. Quisque vel
            ultricies nisi. Vestibulum eu ante risus. In ultrices dignissim massa, vel luctus dui consequat quis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```